# Error while returning integer instead of Scanner.NextInt()

Tags: java, return, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a menu-driven Java program to implement a Vigenere Cipher.
For the menu function, I wrote the following code:

```
    public static int printmenu(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Vigenere Cipher!");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1.Encrypt a message");  
        System.out.println("2.Decrypt a message");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        return scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Now this does the job correctly, but I was criticized by my professor for not closing my scanner class object "scan".
So, I made the following edit to my code:

```
    public static int printmenu(){
            int a;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Vigenere Cipher!");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1.Encrypt a message");  
            System.out.println("2.Decrypt a message");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
            a = scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();
            return a;
    }
```

This, however, returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at vigenere.Ciphermain.main(Ciphermain.java:30)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

**Edit:** Here is the source code for the Ciphermain class:

```
public class Ciphermain extends JFrame{

    public static int printmenu(){
        int a;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Vigenere Cipher!");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1.Encrypt a message");  
        System.out.println("2.Decrypt a message");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message, key;
        int choice;
        choice = printmenu();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(choice == 1){
            System.out.println("Enter the message to be encrypted:");
            message = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the secret key:");
            key = scan.next();
            Cipher ciph = new Cipher(key);
            System.out.println("Encrypted message is: " + ciph.encrypt(message));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter the message to be decrypted:");
            message = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the secret key:");
            key = scan.next();
            Cipher ciph = new Cipher(key);
            System.out.println("Decrypted message is: " + ciph.decrypt(message));
        }
    scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me when I run it. Can you show us some more code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing scanner will close underlying stream (System.in). So next time you create scanner on System.in which is closed, you will get such exception.

Create scanner at start of program, use it everywhere and close it at end of program.

Like:

```
static Scanner scan;

static int displayMenu(){
    // display menu.
    return scan.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // start work.

    // end of work.

    scan.close();
}
```

Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()

Comment: I see, so I guess I should initialize the "scan" variable in the Ciphermain class itself, and then simply use this.scan when I use a method, then?

Comment: yes correct. When you close scanner, it will also close System.in stream, and you will no longer be able to read from System.in, i.e. you will not be able to use new scanner again.